# Restrict IIS from working on both IPs in Windows Server 2008

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-server-2008, iis-7

I have the following case:

I created a VM machine for windows server 2008 which have 2 NICs (one with my host, and one as machine internal) and the server is a VPN, DNS and IIS server. From my host, I need to call web site on IIS using DNS (only using VPN). From my host I can either call web server using first IP (from first NIC) or from internal IP (second NIC) after connecting VPN connection.

My problem is that I need to call web server only after connecting VPN, which I couldn't because web server is called from both IP.

Can I restrict ISS to work on both NICs?

By the way I tried to make DNS forward only to one IP but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify the IP address in the Web Site bindings. You can do this by following the below procedures,
From the "`Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager`" window, right click on a web-site, and select "`Edit Bindings...`" In the "`Site Bindings`", select the http, and click "`Edit`" and select the IP address the hostname should bind to.